# Draw a semicircle numbered

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how to draw with tikz a semicircle with angles and lines numbered like this:

```
                   90
              80 mmmmmmm 80
          70 mmm   |    mmm 70
        60mmm      |       mmm 60
     50 mmm        |         mmm 50
 A 40 mmm__________|___________mmm 40 B
  30 mmm           |            mmm 30      
 20 mmm            |             mmm 20
 10 mmm            |              mmm 10
   mmm             |               mmm 
C  ----------------------------------
   10 20 ...          140 150 ...   180
                      D
```

This is an illustration of a 16th cent. author (Juan Perez de Moya, [Tratado de cosas de astronomia y cosmographia y philosophia natural](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2uYm8sb2vakC&dq=Perez%20de%20Moya%20Tratado&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q=concertara%20con&f=false), p. 192. The diagram intends to explain, erroneously though, how to convert parallel degrees to equinoctial degrees, ie., to determine the value in distance of a degree north or south of equator. Moya projects the distance AB onto the equinoctial (it should be numbered every 10º but my drawing doesn't have space) and then converts the degrees of the equinoctial, with a medium value, to leagues or miles. In the figure, the chord AB translated to the equinoctial, i.e., the semi-diameter (numbered from 0 to 180) gives the distance CD, with D placed at 137 degrees (but there is no need to be ticked, in may placed underneath the degrees, just before the 140º).
Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you did not accept a single answer so far? In addition, I believe it is much appreciated on this site if you show some effort on your own and then point out a specific problem.

Comment: I acknowledge I am dummy with tikz. But I am reading the documentation. It just needs time. I took me 5 years to master the reledmac package enough to edit a text (the text for which I need this figure); moreover I did it alone... I understand your comment but these are my limitations.

Comment: **(1)** I understand what you are saying. Still, you can try to provide at least a bit more than just a picture (desired output).  Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/. **(2)** You can easily address/improve the first part of my first comment :).

Comment: **Last try:** "Any reason why you did not accept a single answer so far?"

Answer (score 4):

To draw an arc one can use `\draw arc ...;`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[scale=6] (1,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1]
   coordinate[label=left:{$C$}] (C) -- cycle
   foreach \x in {10,20,...,80}
   { (\x:1) node[rotate=-90+\x,anchor=south] {$\x$}
   (180-\x:1) node[rotate=90-\x,anchor=south] {$\x$}}
   (0,1) coordinate[label=above:{$90$}] (N)
   -- (N|-C)
   foreach \x in {10,20,...,170} 
   {(-1+\x/90,0) node[below]{$\x$}}
   (40:1) coordinate[label=below left:{$B$}] 
    -- (140:1) coordinate[label=below right:{$A$}];   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I insert the D approximately where 137 should be?

Comment: Everything else is perfect.

Comment: @Sintram `\draw[scale=6] (1,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1]
   coordinate[label=left:{$C$}] (C) -- cycle
   foreach \x in {10,20,...,80}
   { (\x:1) node[rotate=-90+\x,anchor=south] {$\x$}
   (180-\x:1) node[rotate=90-\x,anchor=south] {$\x$}}
   (0,1) coordinate[label=above:{$90$}] (N)
   -- (N|-C)
   foreach \x in {10,20,...,170} 
   {(-1+\x/90,0) node[below]{$\x$}}
   (40:1) coordinate[label=below left:{$B$}] (D)
    -- (140:1) coordinate[label=below right:{$A$}] (A)
 (-1+137/90,0) node[below=1.5em] {$D$};`